# What was Kakuzu's original chakra nature element?

Tags: naruto

Kakuzu, an Akatsuki member who works with Hidan as a pair, has a unique ability. His body is full of black strings that he can use to steal the organs of his opponents.

He uses this ability in order to

> steal his enemies' hearts, which gives him two important advantages:
>
> **1)** Provides a type of "immortality". He can have a maximum of 4 hearts but this means he needs to be killed 4 times without him replacing the lost hearts in the mean time.
>
> **2)** Allows him to use the chakra nature elements of the stolen hearts. For example, if he steals a heart from someone who possessed the wind chakra nature element, he'd be able to use that.

Is it known what Kakuzu's own original chakra nature element was?

Comment: Should be 5 hearts. 4 with the mask, 1 with his own body.

Answer (score 6):

Being originally from the Waterfall village plus using the only element without having an embodiment,

I'll have to take an educated guess and call **Water** on Kakazu.

Comment: Naruto is from Konoha, in the Fire Country and his element is Wind...

Comment: @JNat: Konoha is quite special in that sense, because it's a collection of clans left from the early times. It's inherent that most people in the Mist for example are water-style users, and most people in the Sand are wind-style users. Konoha is the only one which don't conform to that rule.

Comment: Ok, I guess you're right.

Comment: @JNat: *also*, like I said, out of all of the five elements he displayed, Water was the only one that didn't have a weird black creature attached to it.

Comment: Still, it is only a guess (or deduction)

Comment: @JNat: like I said, it's an educated guess.

Comment: I'll wait before accepting in case someone else provides something and then accept. :P

Comment: ok. sold! +1 for you!

Comment: Kakashi destroyed a mask, before he could use the element. It would be logical that this heart had the water-element ;).

Comment: Only he used it in battle afterwards. Kakashi destroyed the earth element.

Comment: Kakashi destroyed the Water element mask -- Just because he lost a mask doesn't mean he can't use the element anymore period. Most skilled shinobi can use at least two chakra release types. See -> http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Grudge_Fear

Answer (score 3):

The [Official Character Data book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1421541254/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1M9XSVQKNS3HZPY3Z2R0&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=317828027&pf_rd_i=468294) provides **no info** on this. I'd say that any answer other than this without any strong sources is mere speculation, or some educated guess (as MadaraUchiha's answer).

Answer (score 0):

While impossible to know since many shinobi use multiple chakra elements, **Earth Style** was the only type he used without a mask (http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Release:_Earth_Spear) -- He had masks for Water, Fire, Wind, and Lightning. So I'd say that was probably his natural affinity, or at least what he was most comfortable with/most practiced with in his original body.

Ref: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Grudge_Fear