# Is the nature of chakra hereditary?

Tags: naruto

It's been observed that the nature of the chakra a person possesses is determined by the village they are from.

For example, people from Iwagakure (Village Hidden in the Rocks) use earth release techniques, while people from Kirigakure (Village Hidden in the Mist) possess water-type chakra.

There seem to be exceptions, though.

For example, let's consider Konoha : Naruto possesses wind-type chakra while Kakashi and Sasuke possess lightning. Sasuke also possesses fire.

Is it hereditary, or is there something else that determines it? Or is it random?

The 5th Mizukage possesses 3 types of chakra elements: Earth, Fire and Water. If my supposition is correct, how she could achieve this?

Comment: Sai: I changed your "Village Hidden in the Water Fall" to "Village Hidden in the Mist" because the first one doesn't exist. If you mean another village, like the "Village Hidden in the Rain" (Amegakure), please fix it.

Comment: @kuwaly The Village Hidden in the Water Fall does exist.. It's where Kakuzu is from. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Takigakure   You were right in correcting him because OP mentioned the waterstyle techniques but that doesn't mean the village doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chakra Nature affinities are hereditary. That is why, as you referred, people from the same village or clan generally possess affinity toward the same nature (Uchiha's have a natural affiliation with the Fire Nature). This means that genetically, the affinity is passed from generation to generation, being the one that you are *naturally* connected to. Despite this, it may be possible for shinobi to have affinities that are different from the ones possessed by their parents, although I cannot remember any examples.

However, shinobi are not limited to the nature toward which they have a natural affinity. So one can also master other Chakra Natures *through practice*. Generally, shinobi at Jounin level have mastered more than one Chakra Nature.

Having said that, given the amount of time and practice taken for one to master a Chakra Nature, it is practically impossible to master all five Natures (unless you possess the Rinnegan, the [Bashousen](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Bash%C5%8Dsen), or do it the way Kakuzu did).

You can also check out [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/304/49), that though not exactly the same, may answer some doubts you may have.

---

As for the examples you provide:

- Sasuke has a natural affinity toward Fire Nature (as all Uchiha), and trained in order to master Lightning Nature. However, given how well he masters Lightning Nature, I'd say he may well have had a natural affinity toward it to start with.
- Kakashi's natural affinity is toward Lightning Nature, and he masters other Natures through practice, presumably with the help of the Sharingan (in copying and understanding other shinobi's jutsu).
- Whether Naruto's affinity toward Wind Nature is hereditary or not is unknown, since we do not know what affinities Minato and Kushina were born with (both were proficient in Wind Nature transformation, but also in other Natures: Kushina in Water Nature, and Minato in Fire and Lightning Natures).
- As for the variety of Konoha's shinobi's affinities, check out [this comment from Madara](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/222/whats-kakuzu-original-chakra-nature-element?rq=1#comment302_223).
- As for the case of Mei Terumi, I do not think it is known whether her affinities and Kekkei Genkai were obtained *naturally* or *through practice*.

Comment: Isn't Sasukes natural affinity Lightning? I thought that was the reason Kakashi taught him the Chidori.

Comment: Nope: like I mentioned, [all Uchicha have a natural affinity towards Fire Nature](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sasuke#Nature_Transformation).

Comment: The affinity to lightning was apparently Anime only (when Kakashi asked him to channel his chakra through the chakra paper and it wrinkled instead of burning). For the manga it appears that both lightning and fire are his natural affinities.

Comment: I feel you're correct, JNat, but Bashousen, Rinnegan, and Kakuzu's methods of obtaining all chakra natures aren't the only ways. You can achieve this by using Rikudou Senjutsu as well.

Answer (score 3):

That much is unexplained, however, one can assume that it is to some degree hereditary.

- People from all villages (with the exception of Konoha, which is a unison of multiple multicultural clans), often use element specific techniques to their village (Mist uses water, Cloud uses lightning, etc).
- Kekkei Genkai (genetic techniques) are often meant to be specific elements, which require specific elemental combinations (of two or sometimes more).

It was said that every shinobi has a primary chakra type (Wind for Naruto, lightning for Kakshi, etc), and that they can expand their chakra mastery to further elements (Kakashi knows lightning (primary), earth and water (there's also anime-specific fire)).

Yin and Yang elements seem to be an exception to that rule. It looks like it depends on the shinobi's innate chakra system (Hashirama could use healing techniques, which were implied to be Yang element, but also use Wood, which is a fusion between Earth and Water).

Answer (score 0):

I have though about it for a while the secondary nature that sasuke and Naruto have are based on there past think about it

Lightning is unstable sasuke legit has no one the whole entire uchiha clan was kill be itachi he lived the life in the shadow of is bother who I think if I'm corrrect got jonien at 14 or 15 so yeah his life kinda sucks

Wind is Naruto's calm cool and soft I think this he had people that cared for him examples include iruka and kakashi this isn't say that wind is always calm just look at hurricanes and tornados ether way both elements irl are dangerous under that right conditions like the 2 badass shinobi

Answer (score 0):

It is implied in the manga that chakra affinities are partly genetic and partly influenced by the natural energies of the land. People born in Fire country are more likely to have fire as their primary affinity, Earth country natives to have earth affinity, etc. It does seem to work somewhat like  other heritable characteristics, though, in that individuals from families with some predominant affinity may still be born with a different primary affinity.

In addition, children in some families are born with dual affinities (kekkei genkai) and these are inherent to the bloodline and will be inherited by all of the offspring.

It is stated that most people have more than one affinity, although one is usually dominant, and that secondary affinities can be developed with practice. By the time a shinobi reaches Jounin level, they are pretty much expected to have developed at least one secondary affinity to reasonable levels. Most of the Kage level shinobi seem to have developed two, or more, although not all if them can combine these into kekkei genkai or higher level merges.

Most can also develop at least some proficiency with either Yin release (e.g. shadow manipulation, illusion techniques) or Yang release (e.g. healing or body modification) or both.